# What is an appropriate translations of "That's so Raven!"?

Tags: mandarin, expressions

The phrase in the title comes from a Disney show, [That's so Raven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That%27s_So_Raven). But in my house, we have been confused on the proper way of translating this.

now we are saying "这是大Raven!" with extra emphasis on **dà**.  This is of course a very simplified translation. My wife says "那真Raven!". Is this show even known in China?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this show is particularly popular in China.

A quick search on Baidu gave me results like 天才魔女 (genius girl with magic), 超能力黑少女 (raven girl with superhuman abilities), and the literal 如此瑞文.

If you are just translating the phrase "that's so *_*," it would be 这太 __ or 这也太 __.

For example,

> That's so cool!
>
> 这太酷了吧！ or 这也太酷了吧！

If a name follows "so",

> That's so Josh!
>
> 一看就是Josh做的！ or 典型的Josh作风！

Comment: This is great. Exactly the kind of context based example I was looking for. Thanks!